# PIVOT, Row_Number() returning multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a list of emails onto a single row, but for some reason my primary email address is getting a row of its own, so Im ending up with two rows per contact.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
ID VARCHAR(20)
, EMAIL VARCHAR(50)
, isPrimary VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (ID, EMAIL, isPrimary) VALUES ('B4100358183Q!ZH.ETES', 'ABoyd@Energize.com', '1')
INSERT INTO #tmp (ID, EMAIL, isPrimary) VALUES ('B4100358183Q!ZH.ETES', 'BSykes@Energize.com', '0')
INSERT INTO #tmp (ID, EMAIL, isPrimary) VALUES ('B4100358183Q!ZH.ETES', 'TC6@test.com', '0')
```

How would I amend the script below to return only one row containing all 3 email addresses rather than two rows?

```
SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
  Select ID, EMAIL, isPrimary 
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY isPrimary desc) AS rn
  from #tmp
) eml
PIVOT (
  min(EMAIL)
  FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3])
) P
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `isPrimary` from your `SELECT` where you're calculating the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT ID, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (
  Select ID, EMAIL
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY isPrimary desc) AS rn
  from #tmp
) eml
PIVOT (
  min(EMAIL)
  FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3])
) P
```

---

```
| ID                   | 1                  | 2                   | 3            |
|----------------------|--------------------|---------------------|--------------|
| B4100358183Q!ZH.ETES | ABoyd@Energize.com | BSykes@Energize.com | TC6@test.com |
```

Comment: Aaah, I understand now. 
That does indeed resolve the issue.

Thanks for you speedy response.